# Combine or call two APIs at once (multiple scope)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, azure, token

There may not be an answer to this question, but I just want to make sure that my situation cannot be solved in any way.

The essence of my application (and, accordingly, the problem) is that each user has only his own individual database, and does not have access to the databases of other users.
The app prompts the user to sign up with Microsoft Azure. I'm sending a request to get
token with code

> const tokenRequestScope = `${clientId}/.default`;

and if everything goes well, then the user is automatically redirected to the first page of the application.

But I would also like to display the user's photo from account Microsoft Azure in the header of my application. And I can get a photo only by request

> const tokenRequestScope = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/.default'

And the photo is displayed.

But here the question arises that when using this request, the data from the database of a particular user (clientId) is not loaded (the application is in endless loading).

Thus, at the moment I can either display the user's photo in the application or upload content

In this regard, the question is, can I combine two requests into one, or use other ways to solve this problem?

microsoft_auth.js

```
const clientId = config.microsoftAuth.clientId;
const tenantId = config.microsoftAuth.tenantId;

const scope = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/User.Read offline_access';
const tokenRequestScope = `${clientId}/.default`;
// const tokenRequestScope = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/.default';

const codeVerifier = '';
const codeChallenge = '';
const codeChallengeMethod = '';

const localPort = '3000';
const localHost = 'localhost';

const host = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com';
const baseUrl = `${host}/${tenantId}/oauth2/v2.0`;

const redirectUri = window.location.host == `${localHost}:${localPort}`
    ? `http://${localHost}:${localPort}`
    : `https://${window.location.host}`;


function signInWithPopup() {
    _requestAuthCode();
}

async function requestTokens(authCode, state = '') {
    let tokensResponse = await _requestTokens(authCode, state);

    if (tokensResponse.status == 200) {
        return tokensResponse.data;
    }
}


function _requestAuthCode() {
    let authCodeRequestUrl = `${baseUrl}/authorize?` +
        `client_id=${clientId}` +
        `&response_type=code` +
        `&redirect_uri=${redirectUri}` +
        `&response_mode=query` +
        `&scope=${scope}` +
        `&code_challenge=${codeChallenge}` +
        `&code_challenge_method=${codeChallengeMethod}`;

    window.open(authCodeRequestUrl, "_self");

}

async function _requestTokens(authCode, state = '') {
    let tokensRequestUrl = `${baseUrl}/token?`;

    const config = {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        }
    };

    let body = {
        'client_id': clientId,
        'scope': tokenRequestScope,
        'code': authCode,
        'redirect_uri': redirectUri,
        'grant_type': 'authorization_code',
        'code_verifier': codeVerifier,
    };

    

    const response = await axios.post(tokensRequestUrl, body, config);
    return response;
}

async function check_auth_code(authCode, onSuccess, onError) {
    if (authCode) {
        const data = await requestTokens(authCode);

        if (data) {
            localStorage.setItem('access_token', data.access_token);
            localStorage.setItem('refresh_token', data.refresh_token);
            console.log('Success login');
            onSuccess();
        }
        else {
            console.log('Error login');
            onError();
        }
    }
}



function isLogin() {
    return localStorage.getItem('access_token');
}


export { signInWithPopup, requestTokens, check_auth_code, isLogin };
```

Answer (score 0):

> Note that, it's **not possible** to pass both scopes at once and acquire access token for them.
>
> Alternatively, you can make use of **on-behalf of flow** by passing access token acquired for `${clientId}/.default` as **assertion** value and generate token for Microsoft Graph.

I have registered one SPA application and exposed an API by adding **scope** like below:

[image]

Now, I added below **`API permissions`** in that application and granted admin consent like this:

[image]

I used below authorization end point to get **`code`** value:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantID>/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
client_id=appID
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=https://jwt.ms
&response_mode=query
&scope= api://<client_id>/.default
&code_challenge=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
&code_challenge_method=S256
```

When I ran above endpoint in browser, I got **code** value successfully in address bar like this:

[image]

I generated access token using **PKCE flow** with `${clientId}/.default` scope via Postman like below:

```http
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantID>/oauth2/v2.0/token

grant_type:authorization_code
client_id:appID
scope: api://<client_id>/.default
code:<paste_code_from_above_step>
code_verifier:S256
redirect_uri: https://jwt.ms
```

**Response:**

[image]

Now, I generated **access token** for Microsoft Graph using **on-behalf of flow** by passing above token in `assertion` like this:

```http
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantID>/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:appID
client_secret:secret
scope: https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
grant_type: urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer
assertion:<paste_token_from_above_step>
requested_token_use:on_behalf_of
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I used above token to call following query, I got **profile photo** of signed-in user successfully like below:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/photo/$value
```

**Response:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you for paying attention to my question. I will try to implement your solution method and get back to you with feedback

Comment: I did the first two steps (on azure) from your answer. And I have already tried many options, modifying the microsoft_auth.js file according to your next steps. But still did not achieve the desired result. Maybe I'm making some mistake. Could you tell me exactly what to change in my microsoft_auth.js file?

Comment: Change `scope` and `tokenRequestScope` to **${clientId}/.default** scope and generate an access token. Once done, decode it in [jwt.ms](https://jwt.ms) and check `aud`, `scp` claims.

Comment: aud - it is Application ID, scp: "Directory.Read.All User.Read"

Comment: Can you help me resolve this issue completely?

Comment: Could you include the decoded token screenshot by editing your question? If `aud` is application id, then `scp` should have permissions exposed in API not Microsoft Graph permissions.

Comment: Could you try adding `api://` as prefix in scope parameters? It should be **`api://<client_id>/.default`**

Comment: When I run the code with
const scope=`api://${clientId}/.default`;
const tokenRequestScope=`${clientId}/.default`;
Then I don’t get an access token at all and, accordingly, I can’t enter the application

Comment: Could you directly pass the hardcoded `clientID` once and check? The decoded token should have `aud` and `scp` claims like [this](https://i.imgur.com/QHGqzDd.png).

Comment: what does the phrase "directly pass the hardcoded clientID" mean? Explain, please

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254159/discussion-between-sridevi-and-paul).